# vuetify 3 v-text-field conditional append-icon does not show

Tags: vuejs3, icons, vuetifyjs3

I want to hide a key (default) when a user enters the page but with the click on the mdiEye Icon (append-icon) the user can make the key visible. Therefore I build the following code.

```
<v-text-field
  class="mt-1"
  v-model="key"
  counter
  maxlength="80"
  hide-details="auto"
  variant="outlined"
  readonly
  :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdiEye' : 'mdiEyeOff'"
  :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
  @click:append="show1 = !show1"
></v-text-field>
```

...

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { mdiPlus, mdiMinus, mdiLinkBoxVariantOutline, mdiEye, mdiEyeOff  } from '@mdi/js';

let key = ref("ffffffdddddssss3333333")
let show1 = ref(false)

</script>
```

I also installed mdi/js an when I simply display the icon (`<v-icon>{{ mdiEyeOff }} </v-icon>`) it works perfectly fine.

What do I do wrong? Is there something wrong with the binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the svg imports from `@mdi/js`, you have to pass them as objects, not strings:

```html
<v-text-field
  :append-icon="show1 ? mdiEye : mdiEyeOff"
  ...
/>
```